# Quadratic Solver giving output NaN

Tags: java, quadratic

I'm extremely new to java and I was asked to program a quadratic equation solver for a class in school. I'm not sure if my code is even remotely correct, but I get the output "NaN" for whatever input I give.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;

public class FunTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      String number1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter A");
      int a=Integer.parseInt(number1);

      String number2=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter B.");
      int b=Integer.parseInt(number2);

      String number3=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter C.");
      int c=Integer.parseInt(number3);

      double discriminantsquared=((b^2)-(4*a*c));
      double discriminant=Math.sqrt(discriminantsquared);

      double x1=(((b*-1)+discriminant)/(2*a));
      double x2=(((b*-1)-discriminant)/(2*a));

      String output=("x1= "+x1+"\n"+"x2= "+x2);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
    }
}
```

Comment: *I'm not sure if my code is even remotely correct*. Then why would you be surprised by any output? And what is your question exactly?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in your IDE debugger?  Please do at least that before asking here so you can at least pinpoint where the problem is.

Comment: You say you're new to Java, but perhaps you've had experience in other languages?  Please be aware that the "power" operator is one that changes from language to language.  Some languages use `^`, some languages use `**`, and Java doesn't have an operator.

Comment: Once you fix the obvious bug identified by @Murelnik you still have to add some code to deal with quadratics that have no roots (i.e. `discriminantsquared < 0`)

Answer (score 4):

`b^2` is not "b to the power of two", it is "b [xored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Computer_science) with 2". For power you could use [`Math.pow(b, 2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-), or simply `b * b`.

Comment: b * b is superior in every way, but a good spot for the reason.